# Cinema Paradiso International (124 min) Release: What Happened to the shot of the woman in the ending credits?

Tags: alternate-version, cinema-paradiso

When I saw Cinema Paradiso in the theater in 1988, the international 124-min release, at the very end of the ending credits we saw a middle-aged woman who looked like Toto's teenage love interest.

Then we saw middle-aged Toto noticing her and pondering the possibility that it was his old love before the screen went black.

All the home versions of that film I've ever seen have removed that one shot of the middle-aged woman and we just see Toto pondering something (we don't know what).

What happened to this wonderful detail in the ending credit roll and has anyone seen a version that has it?

P.S. I am not looking to watch the director's 173-min cut or the original 155-min cut. I am talking about the 124-min one.